# How do I request my teacher to stop apologizing and being too nice when correcting my mistakes?

Tags: interpersonal-issues, communication

I have a teacher who honestly is a bit over the top. I like her teaching skills and appreciate being in her class. Sometimes, though, when I'm having a debate with her, she disagrees with me.

> Me: Presents a Claim
>
> Teacher: That's not even close, oh sorry I didn't mean to be so rude

To be honest that kind of gets on my nerves and disrupts my learning. If she keeps on apologizing, then how am I truly supposed to learn that my ideas are wrong, and I need to improve? How should I convey to her that she should stop being nice? This is kind of difficult because it sounds strange, asking someone to stop being nice. Is there a way I can convey it to her in a sensible way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She is trying to overcompensate in the presence of lack of knowledge about how rude it was from your perspective. A good first gesture is

> I learn a lot from our interactions and disagreements. I just wanted to express that I never thought you were rude at any time. Please know that there is no need to apologise.

That should give her the required hint. It is difficult to predict if she will take it, but I suggest not to be pushy. On your side, you can try to be more accommodating when she is apologising, and repeat the above remarks.